# select values with same id but different in other column

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I've got this table.

OWNS:

```
Pid Cid
100 1
100 2
200 1
200 3
300 4
400 1
400 4
400 5
500 2
500 4
```

I need to select only Pid who have Cid = 1 but not Cid = 2
the output should be:

```
pid
200
400
```

My query is:

```
SELECT Pid
FROM OWNS 
WHERE Cid = 1 and Cid <> 2
```

but I get result :

```
pid
100
200
400
```

Comment: You expectations are wrong. 100, 200 and 400 have rows with cid = 1. Also the Cid <> 2 in combination with and cid = 1 makes no sense, as 1 is always <> 2 Edit: My fault. got the question wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT distinct Pid 
FROM OWNS 
WHERE 
   Pid not in (select Pid from OWNS where Cid = 2) 
AND CID = 1;
```

Comment: Edited. Try it now please.